# How can you pass the value of a variable from drupalSettings to an iframe in the same page?

Tags: 8, javascript

I have a variable in Drupal settings which gets its value from php.

```
 (function ($, Drupal, drupalSettings) {
 /**
  * @namespace
  */
 Drupal.behaviors.pdf_appAccessData = {

attach: function (context) {
  var value = drupalSettings.value_set;
 }
 };
})(jQuery, Drupal, drupalSettings);
```

How can I set this value to be available in the iframe of the page? I tried in the iframe:

```
 <script>
xx = parent.value;
alert (xx);
</script>
```

but it is not working.

Note: the value is supposed to be secret...I managed to do it in Drupal 7 by adding in the js file above (function ($, Drupal, drupalSettings) { var value; to make the variable global and accessible in the page.

Comment: Welcome to Drupal Answers! :-) Seems this hasn't much to do with Drupal. You can try to pass it via URL query parameters. https://stackoverflow.com/q/28295870/2199525

Comment: No I can't because it is supposed to be secret...I managed to do it in drupal 7 by adding in the js file above  (function ($, Drupal, drupalSettings) { var value; to make the variable global and accessible in the page

Comment: Use of configuring X-FRAME-OPTIONS on the web server that is serving the iframe is probably off-topic. You could also use a message system to communicate between a frame and its parent or some other ways:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/935127/how-to-access-parent-iframe-from-javascript